# How can I get information on who is downloading my plugin? (new to this)

Tags: plugins, directory

I have a WP plugin that I contracted. We only have a front end developer/designer working on it. No real back end at all, yet.

Right now, the only information we have is through the plugin directory.

What are some simple solutions for being able to track who is downloading the plugin, who is activating it, and how the found it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native solution for this. I remember there was a third party service specializing in theme analytics, but can't google it up now (might have been discontinued).

You should also note that official plugin directory severely prohibits gathering such information without explicit user consent. See the guidelines:

> 1. No "phoning home" without user's informed consent. ...
>
> http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/guidelines/

About only popular plugin I remember doing tracking (with consent and stuff) is WP SEO, you can look at [their implementation](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wordpress-seo/trunk/admin/class-tracking.php) for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I won't break any WP rules and would make sure there is clearly user consent. It seems to me like anyone who was serious about improving their WordPress plugin  would desire this information.